# Best Practise - python logger.debug различные yровни логгирования debug

Tags: python, отладка, логирование, best-practice

Какие существуют рекомендации по написанию логгирования для режима debug в коде? Как правильно реализовать различные уровни (от 1 до 5 по уровню деталиазации) логгирования для указного режима? Например при включении debug_level <= 3 выводить сообщения в файл логгирования, а если debug_level  > 3 тогда выводить debug информацию только на консоль.

Comment: Реализовать или использовать? Разные уровни логирования уже реализованы в стандартном модуле `logging`

Comment: Реализовать и использовать.  Можете привести пример ?

Comment: Зачем реализовывать готовое? Могу! Из какого-нибудь проекта в ответ приложу пример логирования, обычно простого print хватает :)

Comment: Могу предложить как это сделать: заводите логгеры для каждого типа вывода (консоль output, консоль errput, файл, сеть, почта и т.п.) заводите свою функцию для вывода в debug и в нее передаете debug_level, а уже в зависимости от значения используется конкретный логгер. Можно даже не передавать значение debug_level, а завести ее как глобальную переменную

Comment: а пример можно ?  я тоже думал о таком же варианте, но думал, что возможно что-то получше в серии Best Practice

Comment: Лучшие практики логирования -- это https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html :)

Comment: И все-равно я не понимаю, зачем вам debug_level, когда уже есть уровни логирования: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#levels Их хватит для всего, да и уровни детализации есть: от NOTSET до CRITICAL

Comment: Это я видел и знаю и использую. Иногда требуется различный уровень debugging (с различным уровнем детализации). К примеру я хочу отловить  логическую ошибку. Для этого я включаю логгирование для debug,  но в коде очень много мест где прописан log.debug и фактически лог файл у меня будет заполнен    избыточной информацией по debug. Чтобы этого избежать лучше использовать debug_level  и в различных частях кода указывать свой уровень логгирования для debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привожу простой пример логгирования в консоль и файл с кастомный форматом логов:

```
def get_logger(name, file='log.txt', encoding='utf8'):
    import sys
    import logging

    log = logging.getLogger(name)
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(filename)s[LINE:%(lineno)d] %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')

    fh = logging.FileHandler(file, encoding=encoding)
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    ch = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)

    log.addHandler(fh)
    log.addHandler(ch)

    return log
```

Пример использования:

```
log = get_logger('my_log')
log.debug('Start')

timeout = 1000
log.info('Timeout %s', timeout)

log.warn('Not found time!')
log.error('Error while requests')

log.debug('End')
```

Результат в консоли и в файле:

```
[2017-04-03 13:34:25,047] FOO_TEST_TEST.py[LINE:32] DEBUG    Start
[2017-04-03 13:34:25,047] FOO_TEST_TEST.py[LINE:35] INFO     Timeout 1000
[2017-04-03 13:34:25,048] FOO_TEST_TEST.py[LINE:37] WARNING  Not found time!
[2017-04-03 13:34:25,048] FOO_TEST_TEST.py[LINE:38] ERROR    Error while requests
[2017-04-03 13:34:25,048] FOO_TEST_TEST.py[LINE:40] DEBUG    End
```

---

Уровень логирования задается не случайно, это является фильтром, например если в `get_logger` подправить строку для `ch` и изменить уровень с `DEBUG` на `ERROR`, то в консоль попадут логи с серьезностью от `ERROR` и выше:

```
ch = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

В консоли будет только:

```
[2017-04-03 14:04:02,742] FOO_TEST_TEST.py[LINE:40] ERROR    Error while requests
```

В файле будет полный лог как в первом примере

Comment: Спасибо за пример, но это не то, что хотелось бы увидеть. На примере вашего кода, требуется чтобы debug информация выгружалась только в случае если только если включен уровень debug >= 3.   Вопрос - как именно этот уровень задавать и проверять правильно.

Comment: Добавьте в ваш вопрос больше информации, желательно с примерами (можно и метакод который описывает их), так будет проще на него ответить :)

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, обновил ответ

Comment: Добавил примеры в основной вопрос